# Creating an SQL select statement out of excel values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with 2 columns. I need to CONCATENATE the two cells within each row to create a large WHERE statement in the SQL based off every row. For example:

Where A1 = 'B1' and A2 = 'B2' etc etc.

What do you suggest is the best method to do this? I need to do this across many sheets. Originally I was going to do something like this: C1=CONCATENATE(A1," = ","'",B1,"'") across every row, then CONCATENATE those outputs as well (C1,D1 etc) but just wondering if there are any other options? Would using VBA be easier?

Comment: IMO, your approach should be reasonably fast

Comment: @John Jones, did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use any functions.

You may do like this,

assuming your excel sheet is like:

```
    |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
1   |  a1 |  b1 |     |     |
2   |  a2 |  b2 |     |     |
3   |  a3 |  b3 |     |     |
4   |  a4 |  b4 |     |     |
```

Insert one new row between A and B, and write `='` in cell B1 and drag that cell to COPY cell value upto total number of your rows. Similarly write `' and` in Cell D1 and do same, so it will be like this.

```
    |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
1   |  a1 |  =' |  b1 |' and|
2   |  a2 |  =' |  b2 |' and|
3   |  a3 |  =' |  b3 |' and|
4   |  a4 |  =' |  b4 |' and|
```

Now, Copy paste these cells to **[Notepad++](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2011/07/05/replace-n-with-new-line-characters-using-notepad/)** and replace `TAB` and `\n` by a `space` (new lines)

So, now you should get string like,

```
a1='b1' and a2='b2' and a3='b3' and a4='b4' and
```

You just have to edit minor thing, place this to your query and remove last `and`